# Can't print a generator expression in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried `print(list(....))` which should work but in this case, it doesn't.

I am creating a `dictionary` with `directory` names as `keys` and a `list` with the `file` names in each `directory` as the as `values`. I am using `os.walk`.

```
import os
d = {}
for x,y,z in os.walk(path_folders):
    for f in y:
        if f not in d:
            d[f] = []
        d[f].append(i for i in z)    

print (d)
```

I get the `dictionary` as an output but I can't `print` or `loop` through the `values` which are `generator expressions`. Again, I tried `list` and `loop` but it's not working.

```
{'folder4': [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000004B8B798>], 'folder5': [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000004B8BCF0>], 'subfolder6': [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000004B95E10>], 'subfolder4': [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000004B8B990>], 'subfolder5': [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000004B95360>], 'forder2': [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000004B8BC18>], 'folder6': [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000004B8B510>], 'folder3': [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000004B853A8>], 'folder1': [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000004921CF0>]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `extend` instead of `append`. The problem is you aren't iterating through the generator to get the results, instead you are just putting the promise of results in the dictionary.

This code worked for me.

```
import os

path_folders = "/path/to/stuff"

d = {}
for x,y,z in os.walk(path_folders):
    for f in y:
        if f not in d:
            d[f] = []
        d[f].extend(i for i in z)

print (d)
```

**Edit:**

Ok I must have missed something earlier... The dirnames is a list of all directories in that directory, and filenames is just all the files in that one directory, not the sub directories. I knew something was off about it. So I limited the scope to a folder that I can easily see what files are in there and did some testing. We were making it more complex than it had to be.

```
import os

path_folders = "/path/to/stuff/limited"

d = {}
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path_folders):
    d[dirpath] = filenames

print(d)
```

`dirpath` is the full path.
`dirnames` is all the directories in that path.
`filenames` is all the files in that path.

If you want the current folder name that all those paths are in you are going to need to trim `dirpath` to get it. `dirpath.split('/')[-1]` should do that for you.

With the above trimming and code I get these results.

```
{'directory1': ['file1', 'file2'], 'directory2': ['file3', 'file4']}
```

Comment: Then I get empty lists `dict_values([[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []])`

Comment: Are there files in those directories?

Comment: I saw your last edits but I still get empty lists as values. I have image files in the folders but that shouldn't cause this problem. I can't understand what's going on.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out now. Take a look. :)

Comment: YES!!! You're absolutely right on! It's working! AND you're totally right, I should have kept it simple. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry it took me 3 tries to get it right. ;)

Comment: Hey, thanks for not giving up trying! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Use `d[f] = z` in place of `d[f].append(i for i in z)`

```
import os

d = {}

for x, y, z in os.walk(path_folders):
    for f in y:
        d[f] = z    

print (d)
```

or

```
import os

d = {}

for x, y, z in os.walk(path_folders):
    for f in y:
        if f not in d:
            d[f] = []
        d[f] += z    

print (d)
```

Comment: I tried both but both return empty `lists`. The files in the folders are images could that possibly be the issue. I don't think so because this should just return a `list` of `file` name regardless of the `file type`. I just can't imagine why I get these empty lists or the `generator expressions` that I can't `print`.

Comment: then `print(x,y,z)` to check what you get. Maybe you have wrong `path_folders`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os
d = {}
for x,y,z in os.walk(path_folders):
    for f in y:
        if f not in d:
            d[f] = []
        d[f].extend([i for i in z])    

print (d)
```